# Background image display specific portion of the image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I have an `image` here that I only want a specific position what to display. But mine is not working. I only want the hands to view without cropping the original `image`. Thanks in advance

[image]

Expected result

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
            <h1>できる限り<br>
                自然な形で育てた<br>
                こだわりの野菜です。</h1>
            <h4>生産者／川口太郎・川口久美子さん（安芸市）</h4>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.banner{
    background: url(../img/img1.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 32% 0 5% 6%;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    border-radius: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combination of `background-size` and `background-position` CSS attributes. Dont forget you can make the background-size value greater than 100%. I would throw this at it and fine tune from there:

```
.banner{
  background: url(../img/img1.png);
  // background-size takes height and width but shorthand is one value used for both
  background-size: 200%;
  // background-position options include center, cover, and more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Its working but is there another way? because i'm also using it in my other background image. But different position

Comment: Not sure I understand, you can use the same image as background for multiple different elements, each with their own CSS values. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Simran is super close. You just need to put a specific `background-position` value in. It would need to be something like `background-position: -10% -15%`. Or you can put in `px` or `em` or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Clip. You can crop your image on the page without having to edit the original image source file.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

Comment: but its only applicable in html `img` mine is in the css

Comment: this is a CSS property, just applied to img tags

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for the heads up. I thought that edit was quite odd, but I just wasn't in the mood to engage in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Looking your expected image, I thing you can try this:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: top;
```